# Visual Studio Project - ASP.NET MVC2 - Visual Studio 2010 - Using two machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a laptop and a desktop, I am using them both to work on an ASP.NET MVC2 Project. They are both running Visual Studio 2010 professional. How would I get it so they can both work on that Project (some form of built in version control?)

I have some ASP.NET hosting on GoDaddy if that helps?

Cheers, 
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 'Cloud'

- CodePlex
- SourceForge

Locally

- TFS Workgroup Edition

Answer (score 1):

You can go down the path of SVN and Visual SVN with Tortoise but it might be overkill - and I always find Tortoise slows my machines down by hanging Explorer. I used to do this but I have swapped to using my dropbox (www.dropbox.com) I have the Windows app installed on all my machines and I just create my VS2010 projects within the dropbox folder and they are automatically kept up-to-date provided they are on the net. It works a treat when it's just you on 2 or more machines :-)

I had a power failure at my place the other night - I was able to jump on my laptop and keep working on my project without any interruptions or loss of work :-)

Comment: I would certainly recommend using a version control system even if you are a sole developer! You could, for example, try Mercurial which works with CodePlex and Google Code, or you could just keep the repository on your Dropbox, if that's what you like.